# Images not appearing properly in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm facing an issue in `UIImageView` that images are not appearing properly. I am using collectionView in which I have used a custom cell. I have set:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

I want images to look like this in Android:

Comment: try with  aspect fit

Comment: or you can try with aspect fill as well

Comment: check out the Android App screenshot for the idea

Answer (score 2):

First set ImageView to AspectFill mode,

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

than Try cropping out the rest by using.

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

this should do the trick..

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `contentMode` to `.scaleAspectFill`.  This will scale the image so that the entire image view is filled while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image.  Your current setting, `.scaleToFill`, fills the image view but does not preserve the aspect ratio, so the image looks distorted.

Note that `.scaleAspectFill` may result in some image cropping if the image does not match the aspect ratio of the image view. You can see that this is occurring in your Android screenshot; the hair of the second person is out of view on the right of the first image.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the content mode to `.scaleAspectFill` instead. It will fill the image view with the image but keeping it's aspect ratio.

You may use `.scaleAspectFit` if you want avoid cropping of your images. But in this case the image view is not entirely covered with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

or

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

The first one will fill the frame, possibly cutting off parts of your image. The second one will show the entire image, possibly leaving areas of the frame open.